# How can i set Padding to style of the MainWindow in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

How can i set Padding to style of the MainWindow in QT?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    w.setStyleSheet("padding: 10px;");
w.show();
return a.exec();
```

}

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setStyleSheet()` function:

```
mainWindow->setStyleSheet("padding: 10px;");
```

Comment: I want to set Padd to my App like this App:          http://0000.2.img98.net/out.php/i12978_without-defualt-title-andframe.jpg

Comment: Yes, you can see it in Question.

Comment: The main code looks fine to me. How about the MainWindow code?

Comment: All the code looks right to me. I think it might have something to do with the way your UI elements are added to the main window. It's not sure there's a built-in way to add the padding but, just in case, try `w->setStyleSheet("margin: 10px;");` instead.